# dividing database table data into two but what if count is odd

Tags: mysql

I want top half and bottom half of data of one table I am using queries which works fine  when count is even

```
select count(*) from reviews
select * from reviews limit count/2
select * from  reviews offset count/2
```

but these queries fails when count is odd

kindly give any solutions

php code

```
public function getdatedata($data,$data1){
    if(empty($data) && empty($data1) ) return false;
    $data1 = $data1/2;
    $empty='';
$sql = "SELECT ";
$sql .= $this->reviews.".*";
$sql .= " FROM ".$this->reviews;
$sql .= " WHERE DATE(reviews_date)  = '" . $data . "' LIMIT  CEIL(". $data1.")";

$result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return $result;
     }            else
     { return  $empty ;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CEIL` to round the result:

```
select count(*) from reviews
select * from reviews limit CEIL(count/2)
select * from  reviews offset CEIL(count/2)
```

You can also use `FLOOR` or `ROUND`, whatever you like.

Comment: #1327 - Undeclared variable: ceil this eror is comming

Comment: SELECT reviews.* FROM reviews WHERE DATE(reviews_date) = '2017-10-29' LIMIT CEILING(1.5)

Comment: version is 4.6.4

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `CEIL` or `CEILING`. The problem is your `count`. I copied your queries assuming they worked as you said. Did you declare the `count` as a variable somewhere?

Comment: sir in php it is declared variable giving you code snippet in my question check it out how I am using this

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get what you said. If the `count` variable is declared in PHP, you'll have to run the queries there and pass the variable, exactly like you run your original queries.